# Springjmslistner - Max number of Redeliver in CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE mode

Tags: jms, message-queue, spring-jms

I would like to understand what is the maximum number of re-deliver in CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE if you are not doing the acknowledgment.

1. Do we have any maximum number configured, if so what is that
   property and can we override it?
2. If we don't have any maximum
   number, then the message will always stay in the queue? is there any
   way to clear it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not part of the JMS specification; some vendors have a mechanism to deliver to a dead letter queue after some number of (configurable) attempts.

Recent brokers provide the delivery count in the `JMSXDeliveryCount` header so you can decide to throw it away when the count reaches some number.

If you are using CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE and don't do so, it won't be redelivered at all (unless you close the consumer/connection).

Comment: thanks for your comments. I found that the maximum values can be set as in ActiveMQConnectionFactory as setRedeliveryPolicy. Also, I am getting the redeliver back using CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE when there is an exception throw in the consumer